# Basic Angular Input Control

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, cookies, cookiestore

I have a basic input control which has three bound events to it.  The control displays a year value.  On each event, the control should store it's value in a cookie so that on page refresh, the current value stays the same.

**Events:**

1. `onchange` of the `input` itself (obviously)
2. An arrow to the left of the `input` increments it
3. An arrow to the right decrements it

I know how to do all of this in JQuery, but I'm trying to set this controller up in Angular.  The control works great when you increment/decrement, but when the user manually edits the input, neither increment/decrement function work.  I'm also suspicious that this is a very poor way to build this type of control... Below is my attempted code:

**JS:**

```
myApp.controller('TimeframeCtrl', ['$scope',
                                   '$cookieStore',
                                   function ($scope, $cookieStore) {
  // If year cookie doesn't exist
  if($cookieStore.get('year') == null) { 
    // Create year cookie
    $cookieStore.put('year', 2014); 
  }
  // Decrement year
  $scope.prevYear = function() {
    $scope.year = $scope.year - 1;
    $cookieStore.put('year', $cookieStore.get('year') - 1); 
  }
  // Increment year
  $scope.nextYear = function() {
    $scope.year = parseInt($scope.year) + 1;
    $cookieStore.put('year', $cookieStore.get('year') + 1); 
  }
  // User manually changes year
  $scope.yearChange = function() {
    // Not implemented
  }
  // Set timeframe control value
  $scope.year = $cookieStore.get('year');
}]);
```

**HTML:**

```
<form class="navbar-form pull-left" ng-controller="TimeframeCtrl">
  <i class="fa fa-angle-left" ng-click="prevYear()"></i>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{year}}" placeholder="Year" ng-blur="yearChange()"/>
  <i class="fa fa-angle-right" ng-click="nextYear()"></i>
</form>
```

Comment: I'd suggest you use a directive for this, not a controller. And then implement it's jquery logic in `link` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ng-model` to bind to `$scope.year`

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="year" placeholder="Year" />
```

then use `$watch` to detect changes

```
 $scope.$watch('year', function() {
      // year has been manually changed, put your save logic here
   });
```

But really you should create a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), rather than a controller, than you will be able to reuse your component

Comment: Oh... well I don't need to reuse it.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that:

#### html

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="year" placeholder="Year" ng-change="yearChange()"/>
```

and then:

#### js

```
$scope.yearChange = function() {
  $cookieStore.put('year', $scope.year); 
}
```